# How is the path first loaded in

Tags: shell, path

How do shells like `bash` first get the path and/or environment? Is it a file?

Here is what I have tried:

- `/etc/paths` (Apparently exists on MacOS, cannot find on my Debian
  system)
- Simply loading `$path` (Kind of a cheat for what I'm doing, but it is a
  option if it exists)
- Google fu (Only pulls results about how to modify and set the path
  normally via the shell)

Comment: Please specify what Unix this question is aimed at. It happens in different ways depending on Linux distribution and it's different again on the BSDs.

Comment: What question is left after you read the INVOCATION chapter of `man bash`?

Comment: Philippos: Thanks, i was trying to find a close to crossplatform solution, however, because i want to avoid hardcoding a default 'backup' path into my program.

Kusalananda: Its aimed at Debian and related systems, but information about other systems is welcome

Comment: Well on most BSD systems, the path is set in the `/etc/login.conf` database. I don't know about Debian.

Comment: Bash reads in `/etc/profile` `/etc/profile.d/*` and `~/.profile`. I do not remember any difference on solaris (sysv), sunos (bsd), dec athena, hpux. I may be wrong, but I thing `bash` inherited this behaviour from `sh`.

Comment: @moonheart08, it's more of a question of "what are all the places that environment variables might get set in": there are a few. Of course Bash itself reads certain files, but some envvars might get inherited from the parent process. So, are you in it just out of academic interest, or is there some specific point you are looking for?

Comment: @richard There is a `$PATH` even if you start `bash` with `env -i bash --norc --noprofile`. I believe that the question is "where does this path come from?".

Comment: Apparently there's a hard-coded default `PATH`. But this isn't mentioned anywhere in the `bash` documentation.

Comment: @Barmar There is also `/etc/environment` and `/etc/login.defs` on a Ubuntu system I have access to, but I really can't see what role they play here. Additionally, `getconf PATH` gives a different value. It may be a string constant in the sources, but that sounds _odd_.

Comment: @Kusalananda Try `strings /bin/bash | grep /usr/local/bin` and you'll see it.

Comment: @Barmar Time for you to write an answer it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Normally `$PATH` is inherited from the environment, and shell startup scripts may modify it.

But if the environment variable isn't set, it apparently has a hard-coded default, which depends on the version (or maybe configuration options set when compiling it).

On my OS X system running `bash 3.2.57(1)-release`

```
$ env -i bash --norc --noprofile -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.
```

On Debian running `bash 4.2.37(1)-release`

```
$ env -i bash --norc --noprofile -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

You can confirm that these are hard-coded into the binary by using

```
strings /bin/bash | grep /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Nice to know, makes me not feel like a cheat for using a hardcoded path as a last ditch resort. Thanks!

Comment: Hardcoded defaults of last resort are a good defensive programming practice.